# Spring JPA: How to insert data to join many tables with @ManytoMany relationship

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I'm starting to learn Spring Java Framework . I created some Enity to join 2 Model like my Database. And now I want to insert to Join Table by JpaRepository. What i have to do?
This is my Code (Please fix help me me if something is not right)

Model **Users_RoomId** to define Composite Primary Key

```
@Embeddable
public class Users_RoomId implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Column(name = "ID_room", nullable = false)
private String idRoom;
 @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
 private int idUser;

}
```

Model **Users_Room** to join 2 Model Users and Room

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="bookroom")
public class Users_Room {
 @EmbeddedId
 private Users_RoomId usersroomId;

 @ManyToOne
 @MapsId("idRoom")
 private Room room;

 @ManyToOne
 @MapsId("idUser")
 private Users users;

 @Column(name = "Bookday")
 private String bookday;
```

Model Users and Room I used annotation @OneToMany

**Model Users**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users  implements Serializable{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private int id;


    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;


    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "pass")
    private String pass;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private int role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private List<Users_Room> user;
```

**Model Room**

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="room")
public class Room implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID_room", nullable = false)
    private String id;


    @Column(name = "name_room", nullable = false)
    private String name;


    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String describe;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_status")
    private Status status;

    @Column(name = "room_image")
    private String image;


    public Room() {
        super();
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_kind")
    private KindRoom kind;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "room")
    private List<Users_Room> rooms;
```

This is my database

[image]

So I don't know how to insert a new bookroom with iduser,idroom and bookday with JPA repository.. It'necessary to write Query in JPARepository or We just need to use method save() to insert data

Thanks everyone

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: @JensSchauder thanks for your comment. But your document just do with single table. I want to do with join table

Comment: That is not what you asked in your question. As there are no answers yet please edit the question to actually ask what you want to know. Please include what you tried and in which way it failed.

Comment: Someone can help me please T.T

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solved with following code. I used method save() to insert data. Following code is 'createRoom' method in 'RoomService.java'.

RoomService.java

```
private final RoomRepository roomRepository;
private final UserRoomRepository userRoomRepository;
private final UserRepository userRepository;

public RoomService(RoomRepository roomRepository, UserRoomRepository userRoomRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.roomRepository = roomRepository;
    this.userRoomRepository = userRoomRepository;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

@Transactional
public RoomDto createRoom(Long userId, Long chattingUserId) {
    Room room = roomRepository.save(new Room());

    room.addUserRoom(userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(()->new NoSuchElementException("No User")));
    room.addUserRoom(userRepository.findById(chattingUserId).orElseThrow(()->new NoSuchElementException("No User")));
    userRoomRepository.save(new UserRoom(userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(()->new NoSuchElementException("No User")),room));
    userRoomRepository.save(new UserRoom(userRepository.findById(chattingUserId).orElseThrow(()->new NoSuchElementException("No User")),room));

    RoomDto roomDto = RoomDto.of(room);
    return roomDto;
}
```